# Prestashop Newsletter Module

Tags: php, newsletter, prestashop

I'm looking for the best prestashop newsletter module, that allows me to manage custom newsletter layout and newsletter sending.

Has anyone ever used one? Wich one would you recomend?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that, surprisingly, free newsletter modules for Prestashop are not "common", you should probably try this one : http://www.prestashop.com/forums/viewthread/11284/#49223

You will find the link to the module + a tutorial video in the same thread.

Comment: I think exist by default in version 1.5.3

Answer (score 1):

Last version of this free module here: http://eolia.o2switch.net/eolia/newsletteradmin1.5

Enjoy !

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use mailchimp. I know that there are a lot of solutions how to get emails, how to send it but use official prestashop module to get subscribions. You can open module newsletter and export customers to csv. You can import it to mailchimp. Also you could install mailchimp module to synchronizate this process.

Mailchimp gives opportunity to see detail statistics: who open your newsletter, most popular clicked url`s, successful sent email percent ant who didn`t get email. Here - you could see all data.